# How to handle refresh token in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, axios, refresh-token

I am working on reactjs app in which `access_token` expires after every 5 min. I do have a `refresh_token`. I want to know a way to handle this in reactjs. I tried to do that with some online search But its not working. This is my code below. I am using redux for state management.

> login/action/login.js

```
export const getAccessToken = (dataToSend) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    var formData = ConvertToFormData(dataToSend);
    const authResponse = await Authentication(formData);   <---- This function here gets token from backend api

    const response = await fetch("http://api.xxxx.com/userType", {   <-- endpoint here verify token
      method: "GET",
      cache: "no-cache",
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${authResponse.access_token}`,
      },
    });
    const payload = await response.json();

    if (payload.status === "admin") {
      SaveToLocalStorage("access_token", authResponse.access_token);
      SaveToLocalStorage("refresh_token", authResponse.refresh_token);
      dispatch({
        type: GET_ACCESS_TOKEN,              <--- after getting this dispatch login actions.
        payload: {
          access_token: authResponse.access_token,
          refresh_token: authResponse.refresh_token,
        },
      });
    } else {
      dispatch({
        type: ERROR_ACCESS_TOKEN,
        buttonPressed: true,
      });
    }
  } catch (exception) {
    console.log("Log In again");
  }
};
```

> App.js

```
const middleware = [thunk];
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production") {
  middleware.push(createLogger());
}

const store = createStore(
  reducers,
  composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleware))
);

axios.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
  if (getAccessToken("access_token") === false) {
    return config;
  } else {
    config.headers["Authorization"] = `Bearer ${getAccessToken(
      "access_token"
    )}`;
    return config;
  }
});

axios.interceptors.response.use(
  (response) => {
    return response;
  },
  (error) => {
    const {
      config,
      response: { status },
    } = error;
    const originalRequest = config;
    if (status === 401 && !originalRequest._retry) {
      originalRequest._retry = true;
      const token = userServices
        .getOAuth2()
        .createToken(
          getAccessToken("access_token"),
          getAccessToken("refresh_token"),
          { grant_type: "refresh_token" }
        );

      return token
        .refresh()
        .then((response) => {
          return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const { access_token } = response.data;
            const { refresh_token } = response.data;
            SaveToLocalStorage("access_token", access_token);
            SaveToLocalStorage("refresh_token", refresh_token);
            return resolve(axios.request(originalRequest));
          });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          store.dispatch({
            type: "LOGOUT_USER",
          });
          return Promise.reject();
        });
    } else {
      //here remover every thing and go home and show login modal
    }
  }
);

render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <MuiThemeProvider theme={muiTheme}>
      <CssBaseline />
      <App />
    </MuiThemeProvider>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Comment: Don't save tokens to local storage. They're accessible through JS which means they're susceptible to attacks. Use cookies instead. This also means you won't really have to deal with tokens at all on the front end. The server puts your tokens in the response cookies, and they get sent with every request from the client by default.

Comment: I know how to save token in cookies. But rest of the thing i don't know how to do that.@JMadelaine

Comment: Well you don't need to handle it with React at all if you're using cookies. The client app does not know about the refresh token. So to answer your question "how to handle refresh token in reactjs", the advice is to use cookies and don't handle the refresh token with React. Handle it with your server instead.